# QGIS 3.x Hide form on add feature with Python?

Tags: qgis, python

I use Python for add new tools in QGIS.

How do for access the command "Hide form on add feature with Python" with Python ?

I searched and I didn't find any trick.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution ! In the layer style (.qml file), it need edit this line :

```
  <featformsuppress>2</featformsuppress>
```